# Bootstrap Modal as confirmation prompt after insertion

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Submit and use Modal as a confirmation dialog. But somehow I can't continue with the button's Onclick event after triggering the modal.

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdlSubmitOK" OnClientClick="return false;" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>


     <div id="mdlSubmitOK" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Success!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="OK" OnCommand="SubmitOK_Command" CommandArgument="Yes" class="btn btn-primary"  />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tried this but it did not work in C#.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "mdlSubmitOK", "$('#mdlSubmitOK').modal('show');", true);
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: To trigger the Modal after clicking btnSubmit button. And the code didn't continue to Onclick event.

Comment: Why do you have the `OnClientClick="return false;"` in the `btnSubmit`? That might be the reason

Comment: I removed the line and it worked only once. Then after subsequent clicks, the modal will appear/disappear in split seconds.

Comment: you should share some more code then - like eventhandlers and so on

Comment: I'm triggering from code behind and it works. Will post the solution later.